# AIML interpreter - objective c - gui

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, interpreter, aiml

I want to create an objective c application that interprets a list of .aiml files then make a GUI for it. I want to do this so I can chat with the aiml files within the application.

Any ideas on how to do this?? Sample code? has anyone done this before?

Thanks!

Elijah

Comment: Do you mean AIML as in "Artificial Intelligence Mark-up Language"?

Comment: Yes...ALICE AI has a java version, but I really want to make a nice GUI for it using objective c and xcode. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two ways to do this:

1. Rewrite the java engine in objective C (which will be a huge amount of work.)
2. Use a webservice approach.
   So get an objective c/xcode interface to send messages to a webservice which then uses the standard engine.
   Unfortunately this will mean there will be no offline approach, although it will also mean you can use the same approach on multiple devices with minimal rework.

Answer (score 1):

There is some sample code that can be useful for creating a chatting application; for example, Chatty + MYNetwork (Mooseyard Networking Library, with BLIP protocol implementation):

http://bitbucket.org/snej/chatty/wiki/Home